# How to redirect a user to his own content after log in?

Tags: rules, redirection

I want to redirect a user after log in to his own content.For example lets say a user created a node/3.After log in I want to redirect the user to node/3.How can I do that with rules or with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list the contents of a ( the current) user you can set-up a view and add a filter ar URL argument. To redirect the user to this view after login you can use rules.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ah, I misread the question.  BetaRide's answer is good.  I would just add that the action you will want in Rules is `Page redirect` (under System).